# Compilation fails/imports missing when switching build variants (aar dependencies missing)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Everytime when I switch the buildvariant in android studio all my imports of an aar file fails. To get it working again I need to do one or serval things like cleaning the project, changing something in the gradle file, rebuild or if all doesn't help use the 'invalidate caches / restart" option. Is there a way to make it working correctly?

Here's my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.foo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
    a {
        applicationId "com.example.foo.a"
        versionName "-a"
    }
    b {
        applicationId "com.example.foo.b"
        versionName "-b"
    }
    c {
        applicationId "com.example.foo.c"
        versionName "-c"
    }
    d {
        applicationId "com.example.foo.d"
        versionName "-d"
    }
}
}
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
 bCompile project(':some-aar-for-b-release')
 aCompile project(':some-aar-for-a-release')
 cCompile project(':some-aar-for-c-release')
 dCompile project(':some-aar-for-d-release')
}
```

Comment: Where are you importing an aar file? In the build.gradle you are importing a local project not an aar.

Comment: @Lonzak got any better solution?

Comment: No unfortunatly not...